# I want to restrict my array length to a specific size?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have an `array = []`. I want to restrict the array length. How should I initialize it? Is there anything for restricting the size?in Javascript i cant make it? i have a JSON data with 250 length,i want them to restrict to first 20 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define array size. [**Example**](http://yang-wei.github.io/blog/2015/09/14/initialize-an-array-with-fix-length-in-javascript/):

```
var arr = new Array(5);
```

Comment: This does not restrict the size of the array, it only initilalizes it on construction. You can still do arr.push(...)